# ASP.NET: How can I introduce Aspnet_regsql to Login Controls

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, authentication, asp.net-membership

I setup `aspnet_regsql` in my SQL Server called `SYM\SQLEXPRESS` but it is in the remote computer. As you know, there are some tables created automaticly (Users, Roles, Membership etc). How can I introduce asp.net login controls to this database. Should I change something in `web.config` ? (SYM means 10.10.10.8)

I wathched this video series. http://www.asp.net/security/videos

They just drag&drop login controls in to page. And the database created automaticly. But created their local machine. My question is how can I connect with ASP.NET Login Controls and `aspnet_regsql` database which I have **already exists** in my remote computer?

Comment: I hope this link help you: [aspnet_regsql in my SQL Server](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/asp-net/17/10338762/how-to-implement-aspnet-req-sql-application.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Alternativly, go `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` folder.
2. Run `aspnet_regsql.exe`
3. Write Server Name: `YourServerMachine\SQLExpress`
4. Select Existing Database: `YourTargetDBName` (which you already have)
5. Click Finish.
6. Open WebSite in Visual Studio 2010.
7. Make Changes in `Web.Config

   [image: webconfig]
8. Using Visual Studio 2010 Go to `Website` tab.
9. Click on `ASP.NET Configuration`
10. You can change your security and provider settings.